# Tradução de "tab" em contexto de computação

Tags: tradução-inglês

Em computação, *tab* (componente de interfaces gráficas) é frequentemente traduzida como *aba*, mas vários tradutores automáticos sugerem *guia* como tradução.

Gostaria de saber qual é a situação atual, no Brasil e em Portugal, a respeito do termo técnico utilizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Brasil, não faz diferença. Embora não sejam palavras sinônimas, representam a mesma coisa, ou seja, o índice de fichários.

Nos navegadores:

```
    Mozilla Firefox - **aba**
    Google Chromium - **guia**
```

Answer (score 2):

Vejo *guia* sendo pouco usado na prática, talvez seja mais comum em Portugal.

O [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/tab) sugere também, no sentido de interface gráfica:

- **separador**, que considero bastante ambíguo,
- **marcador**, passível de confusão com *bookmark*, e
- **aba** que, sendo o mais comum e específico, é provavelmente a melhor opção.

O [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/translation/tab.html), que costuma ser uma boa referência, sugere apenas *aba* como tradução de *tab* nesse contexto.